# Why some faces have different colours and can't bridge with others?

Tags: faces

The two selected faces as shown in the screenshot have different colour (slightly brighter) and their edges was unable to bridge with others. What should I do? Any help is appreciated :)

[image]

Comment: Try removing doubles (from `W` menu) and recalculating normals (`Ctrl`+`N`). There seem to be  many double faces between visible ones (probably created while extruding). Also it seems in this case you may create face by `F` instead of `Bridge` tool, it's faster.

Comment: The bright orange and dotted faces are called **"Active Face"**, or the last selected one.